# insert multiple columns based on column name with partial match

Tags: python, pandas, rename, string-matching, partial

i think there will be a simple solution here but i am missing something...

I have two data frames. An original, and a second with some processed data. The column names in the second data frame partially match columns in the first data frame. There are multiple column names with partial matches. The multiple columns from the second data frame need to be reinserted into the same location with a single, partially matched column name in the original data frame (so naturally, the size of the data frame will increase). Examples of the data and the expected output are copied below. it needs to be 'programmatic' as I have lots of these columns/instances.

Any comments are super helpful to me.

Thanks so much!

*original data*

```
df1 = {'id': ['1','2','3','4'],
        'ab': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        'xy': ['1', '2', '3','4'],
        'cd': ['1', '2', '3','4'],
        'ef':['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        'lm':['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        'fa':['1', '2', '3', '4'] }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['id','ab', 'xy', 'cd', 'ef', 'lm', 'fa'])
```

*processed data*

```
df2 = {'id': ['1','2','3','4'],
        'ab? op':  ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'None'],
        'ab? 1': ['red', 'yellow', 'None', 'None'],
        'cd': ['L', 'XL', 'M','L'],
        'efab? cba' : ['husband', 'wife', 'husband', 'None'],
        'efab? 1':['son', 'grandparent', 'son', 'None'],
        'efab? 2':['None', 'son', 'None', 'None'],
        'fab? 4':['9', '10', '5', '3'], 
        'fab? po':['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales', 'NA'] }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = ['id','ab? op', 'ab? 1', 'cd', 'efab? cba', 'efab? 1', 'efab? 2', 'fab? 4', 'fab? po'])
```

*expected output*

```
e = {'id': ['1','2','3','4'],
        'ab? op':  ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'None'],
        'ab? 1': ['red', 'yellow', 'None', 'None'],
        'xy': ['1', '2', '3','4'], 
        'cd': ['L', 'XL', 'M','L'],
        'lm':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
        'efab? cba' : ['husband', 'wife', 'husband', 'None'],
        'efab? 1':['son', 'grandparent', 'son', 'None'],
        'efab? 2':['None', 'son', 'None', 'None'],
        'fab? 4':['9', '10', '5', '3'], 
        'fab? po':['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales', 'NA'] }

expected = pd.DataFrame(e, columns = ['id','ab? op', 'ab? 1', 'xy', 'cd', 'lm', 'efab? cba', 'efab? 1', 'efab? 2', 'fab? 4', 'fab? po'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Python 3.8+, then

```
result = pd.concat([df1[col]
                    if (candidate := df2.loc[:, df2.columns.str.startswith(col)]).empty
                    else candidate
                    for col in df1],
                   axis=1)
```

For each column of `df1`, we look for `candidate` columns in `df2` that `startswith` the column name in `df1`. If such column(s) exist, put the candidate to the result, else keep the column in `df1`.

to get

```
  id ab? op   ab? 1 xy  cd efab? cba      efab? 1 efab? 2 lm fab? 4   fab? po
0  1  green     red  1   L   husband          son    None  1      9   England
1  2    red  yellow  2  XL      wife  grandparent     son  2     10  Scotland
2  3   blue    None  3   M   husband          son    None  3      5     Wales
3  4   None    None  4   L      None         None    None  4      3        NA
```

if 3.8-,

```
cols = []
for col in df1:
    candidate = df2.loc[:, df2.columns.str.startswith(col)]
    cols.append(df1[col] if candidate.empty else candidate)

result = pd.concat(cols, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! so that works for most columns, but it is duplicating some columns where there is only one word or letter difference in the name. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @br101 Can you be more specific as to what describes a "partial match"? I assumed `startswith` but apparently that assumption fails in some of your cases.

Comment: apologies - some column names only differ for a single letter -  before a question mark. for instance, columns from the original may be 'in the last 12 months have you had?' or 'in the last 12 months have you been?' and in the second data frame will be 'in the last 12 months have you ever had? Covid19' , 'in the last 12 months have you ever had? Food poisoning' , 'in the last 12 months have you ever been? to A&E', etc. the only different word before the question mark is been/had (i tried to make it simple in the example but i have made it more difficult). thank you for your help!

Comment: @br101 I'm afraid I didn't fully understand. Maybe you can put some examples and update the question itself, or you might want to ask another question and others might understand and propose solutions, sorry.

Comment: sorry about that you are right its not particularly clear anymore - oi posted a new question here with some different example data which. might help. Thanks again!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67490826/renaming-substring-in-column-names-with-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Something with `argsort` after you combine with two diff with modified columns name

```
c2 = df2.columns.str[:2]
c1 = df1.columns
x = pd.concat([df2,df1[c1[~c1.isin(c2)]]],axis=1)
x = x.iloc[:,x.columns.str[:2].map(dict(zip(c1,range(len(c1))))).argsort()]
x
Out[115]: 
  id ab? op   ab? 1 xy  cd efab? cba      efab? 1 efab? 2 lm fab? 4   fab? po
0  1  green     red  1   L   husband          son    None  1      9   England
1  2    red  yellow  2  XL      wife  grandparent     son  2     10  Scotland
2  3   blue    None  3   M   husband          son    None  3      5     Wales
3  4   None    None  4   L      None         None    None  4      3        NA
```