# renaming substring in column names with dictionary

Tags: python, multiple-columns, rename, str-replace, partial

I hope someone can help. I need to replace part of all column names present in a dataframe using a dictionary shown below. I need to replace the first part (e.g. 'z987') with the respective value in the dictionary for each column (e.g. 'In the last 12 months, have you been to...?'), but keep the second part of the column name (e.g. 'Hospital A&E') so the resultant column name should look like 'In the last 12 months, have you been to...? Hospital A&E'

Many thanks in advance!

*dictionary including mapping between column ids and names*

```
dic = {'z987': 'In the last 12 months, have you been to...?',
 'z769': 'In the last 12 months, have you had...?',
 'ci6hy8': 'When you were a child, had you ever been to...?',
 'cihhm': 'When you were a child, had you ever had...?'}
```

*example data*

```
data =  {'z987 Hospital A&E':['1','0','1'],
        'z987 Hospital inpatient':['0','0','0'],
        'z987 Hospital outpatient':['1','0','0'],
        
        'z769 surgery with local anesthetic':['1','0','nan'],
        'z769 surgery with general anesthetic':['0','0','1'],
        'z769 a severe allergic reaction':['0','0','0'],
        'z769 a broken bone':['1','0','0'],
        'z769 a bacterial infection requiring treatment':['0','0','1'],
        
        'ci6hy8 Hospital A&E':['1','0','nan'],
        'ci6hy8 Hospital inpatient':['1','0','1'],
        'ci6hy8 Hospital outpatient':['1','1','1'],
        
        'cihhm surgery with local anesthetic':['1','0','1'],
        'cihhm surgery with general anesthetic':['1','0','0'],
        'cihhm a severe allergic reaction':['0','0','1'],
        'cihhm a broken bone':['','0','1'],
        'cihhm a bacterial infection requiring treatment':['1','1','nan']}
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

*expected output*

```
e = {'In the last 12 months, have you been to...? Hospital A&E':['1','0','1'],
        'In the last 12 months, have you been to...? Hospital inpatient':['0','0','0'],
        'In the last 12 months, have you been to...? Hospital outpatient':['1','0','0'],
        
        'In the last 12 months, have you had...? surgery with local anesthetic':['1','0','nan'],
        'In the last 12 months, have you had...? surgery with general anesthetic':['0','0','1'],
        'In the last 12 months, have you had...? a severe allergic reaction':['0','0','0'],
        'In the last 12 months, have you had...? a broken bone':['1','0','0'],
        'In the last 12 months, have you had...? a bacterial infection requiring treatment':['0','0','1'],
        
        'When you were a child, had you ever been to...? Hospital A&E':['1','0','nan'],
        'When you were a child, had you ever been to...? Hospital inpatient':['1','0','1'],
        'When you were a child, had you ever been to...? Hospital outpatient':['1','1','1'],
        
        'When you were a child, had you ever had...? surgery with local anesthetic':['1','0','1'],
        'When you were a child, had you ever had...? surgery with general anesthetic':['1','0','0'],
        'When you were a child, had you ever had...? a severe allergic reaction':['0','0','1'],
        'When you were a child, had you ever had...? a broken bone':['','0','1'],
        'When you were a child, had you ever had...? a bacterial infection requiring treatment':['1','1','nan']}

expected = pd.DataFrame(e)
```

Comment: The second batch of statements in `data` should start with `z769` for the given expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```py
df1.columns = [y.replace(x, dic[x]) for x in dic.keys() for y in df.columns if x in y]
```

Essentially, you can iterate over the keys of dictionary and the columns of dataframe and replace the substring with value of the dictionary. Now you can reassign the columns of `df1`